# SSRS - Dynamic Datasets

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, reporting-services

I have a report that uses a stored procedure that can have three different outputs depending upon the selection of a parameter value.

The parameter `Report Type` has the following options:  "Day / Month / Year".

If the user selects "Day", there is an IF statement in the procedure to use tables A and return columns 1, 2, 3.

If the user selects "Month", there is an IF statement to use tables B and return columns 4, 5, 6

Same situation for Year.

So the stored procedure can possibly return:

```
   Select column 1, 2, 3 from Table 1
   Select column 4, 5, 6 from Table 2
   Select column 7, 8, 9 from Table 3
```

As you can see, the dataset I am creating inside my report using this stored procedure, I can't "Refresh Fields" and it pulls in the fields for me to use in my report.

How can I use one stored procedure that has different return values like this in my report so that I can set the fields to show the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your best approach would be to have each case return the same set of column names and types.  If one case returns fewer columns than another then just fill the extra columns with nulls.

Comment: Thank you for the help.  That makes sense and appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in such a way where your SP decides on parameter and does calculations

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.uspGetData @paramValue nvarchar(30)
AS

  Select [column 1] as col1, [column 2] as col2, [column 3] as col3 from [Table 1] where @paramValue=N'Day'
  UNION 
  Select [column 4] as col1, [column 5] as col2, [column 6] as col3 from [Table 2] where @paramValue=N'Month' 
  UNION
  Select [column 7] as col1, [column 8] as col2, [column 9] as col3 from [Table 3] where @paramValue=N'Year'
GO
```